# Swift 3: Converting enum case with associated value to closure with protocol parameter results in a compiler error

Tags: swift, enums, swift3, protocols

I have an enum with an associated value of struct. When I write this code it compiles without error:

```
protocol MyProtocol {}

struct MyAssociatedValue: MyProtocol {}

enum MyEnum {
    case myCase(MyAssociatedValue)
}

func myEnumClosureMapping() -> (MyAssociatedValue) -> MyEnum {
    return MyEnum.myCase
}
```

But than I added another function like this:

```
func mySecondEnumClosureMapping() -> (MyProtocol) -> MyEnum {
    return MyEnum.myCase
}
```

Now I get a compiler error saying: 
`Cannot convert return expression of type '(MyAssociatedValue) -> MyEnum' to return type '(MyProtocol) -> MyEnum'`.

`MyAssociatedValue` struct conforms to `MyProtocol` protocol so this code should compile without errors. What might be the reason of compiler error?

Comment: Who says `T` is of type `MyAssociatedValue`? It could be any concrete type that conforms to `MyProtocol`. Let's say we conformed `Int` to `MyProtocol`, and called `myGenericEnumClosureMapping` with `T` of type `Int` (remember, it's the *caller* that decides the type of `T`, not the callee). If your code was allowed, we could then pass an `Int` to a `MyAssociatedValue`.

Comment: I edited the question to use protocols instead. Still getting a compiler error.

Comment: The problem is the same – you can pass anything that conforms to `MyProtocol` into the returned function (like `Int` if we conformed it), but the associated value is of the specific type `MyAssociatedValue`.

Comment: Note that if you make a force cast `func myEnumClosureMapping() -> (MyProtocol) -> MyEnum {
    return MyEnum.myCase as! (MyProtocol) -> MyEnum
}` in both cases (generic and above) the compiler works fine. I think the problem is that @Hamish and @gnasher729 pointed, without the cast the compiler doesn't know what you're trying to pass it, can be anything and  the _type safe_ property of Swift doesn't allow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't compile. The compiler expects a closure that can map *anything* supporting the MyProtocol protocol to a MyEnum. You are giving it a closure that can only map MyAssociatedValue to a MyEnum. If that closure was called with a MyProtocol that isn't a MyAssociatedValue, then the call would crash, therefore it isn't allowed.